# How do I use a row of custom buttons in a form tag instead of a select drop down menu?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form component which filters data based on the name and category of an asset (ignore the name). I have used the  tag to create a dropdown menu but I want to replace this with an array of custom buttons on a seperate row which filter the data when clicked to give assets of that category. Below is the relevant code I have used.

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col">
        <div className="content-block">
            <a href="" onClick={ (e) => this.props.onResetFilter(e) } className="pull-right">Reset filter</a>
                <h3>
                    Filter
                </h3>
                    <form onSubmit={ (e) => this.props.onTriggerFilter(e) } autoComplete="off">
                        <div className="form-row">
                            <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                                <input 
                                        type="text" 
                                        className="form-control" 
                                        id="name" 
                                        value={this.props.filterData.name}
                                        placeholder="Eg, PDF asset..." 
                                        onChange={({target}) => this.props.onFilterInputChange('name', target.value)} 
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label htmlFor="supplier">Category</label>
                                <select 
                                        name="asset_type" 
                                        className="form-control" 
                                        value={this.props.filterData.asset_type}
                                        onChange={({target}) => this.props.onFilterInputChange('asset_type', target.value, 'select')}
                                >
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        { this.props.assetTypeOptions.map((o, key) => (
                                            <option key={ key } value={ o.value }>{ o.label }</option>
                                        ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" style={{visibility:'hidden'}}>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to replace the select field with a row of buttons in the form

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded waves-effect">Generic</button>
```

and get the data to filter when one is pressed. How do I do that?